# c#Asp.Net Core stdoutLogEnabled=true not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an Asp.Net Core 7 application in which I need to troubleshoot, basically in the application I set Serilog as logger, but I needed to enable the stdoutLogEnabled to get more details. In the web.config I have the following configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
        <system.webServer>
            <handlers>
                <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
            </handlers>
            <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MyApp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess">
                <handlerSettings>
                    <handlerSetting name="debugLevel" value="file"/>
                    <handlerSetting name="debugFile" value=".\logs\ancm.log"/>
                </handlerSettings>
            </aspNetCore>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

I have set all write permissions on the folder. The problem is that the files are created in the log folder, only that the file 'stdout' is empty, there is no log.
Does the fact that I set Serilog as a logger anyway affect this behavior? How can I fix this?
Thank you

**UPDATE**
This is the serilog configuration:

```
private static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .....
        .UseSerilog((hostContext, services, configuration) =>
        {
            configuration.ReadFrom.Configuration(hostContext.Configuration)
                .ReadFrom.Services(services);
        });
```

with configuration file:

```
{
    "Serilog": {
      "MinimumLevel": {
        "Default": "Debug",
        "Override": {
          "Microsoft": "Warning",
          "System": "Information",
          "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "Warning",
        }
      },
      "WriteTo": [
        {
          "Name": "Console",
          "Args": {
            "theme": "Serilog.Sinks.SystemConsole.Themes.AnsiConsoleTheme::Code, Serilog.Sinks.Console",
            "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj} <s1:{SourceContext}> {RequestId}{NewLine}{Exception}"
          }
        },
    ......]
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us your code where you actually configure Serilog. `stdoutLogEnabled` won't work if Serilog is configured to never output to stdout in the first place.

Comment: Sorry in the web.config I set: `hostingModel="inprocess"` Why do you say it's out-of-proc?

Comment: Disregard my comments about in-proc. I've deleted them.